# Good way of storing the location from which request originated rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I was to create some object from different places, ex:

1. I'm creating object from my index page (POSTing to create method of controller)
2. I'm creating object from my show page  (POSTing to create method of controller)

In case of success/error I want to be able to return to the requestors page and display the flash message.

So far I got this working :

```
def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end

def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end
```

But my concern is what if someone else from my team choose to use this piece of code for the similar situation. It might cause the application to redirect to entirely different location.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or how about using the actual request referrer?

Controller:

```
 def create
   ...some create logic
   flash[:success] = 'YEEEY
   redirect_to request.referer
 rescue
   flash[:error] = 'ERROR OCCURRED'
   redirect_to request.referer
 end
```

Comment: I believe 'redirect_to :back' will do the same thing.

Comment: @ihaztehcodez yeah, actually I think it looks neater too

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions could be adding to the form a hidden_field that will allow to distinguish those two cases.

Let's say you have Post model, consider an example:

From show page:

```
<%= form_for @post  do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= hidden_field_tag :return_to, posts_path %>
<% end %>
```

Second form (that is on index page) can be leaved untouched, so it will not pass any value for "return_to" parameter. We would check in a controller if no value passed to "return_to" then consider it as a "Submit from index page" case.

In your controller:

```
def create
   ...
   redirect_to params[:return_to] || posts_path
end
```